# Calculating probability using joint density

Tags: integration, probability-theory, density-function

I'm given the family $(X, Y)$ of random variables with join density:

$$f^{X, Y}(x, y) := 2 \cdot e^{-(x+2y)} \cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}(x) \cdot 1_{[0, \infty)}(y)$$

and I'm required to calculate $P(X > Y)$. I already calculated the marginal density $f^X, f^Y$ and established that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but didn't use this information, but calculated:

$$\int_{\{(x, y)\,\in\,\mathbb{R}^2 : x\,>\,y\}} f^{X, Y}(x,y) \,d(x,y) \\ = \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} 2\cdot e^{-(x+2y)} \cdot 1_{[0, \infty)}(x) \cdot 1_{[0, x)}(y) \,dy\,dx \\= \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{[0, \infty)}(x) \int_0^x 2e^{-(x+2y)} dy\,dx \\= \int_0^\infty e^{-x} - e^{-3x}dx = 1 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Is this approach correct? Do I need to change $x$ in the second equality (since it's part of the bounds) or is it fine, since I integrated $dy$? Can this problem be solves quicker using $f^X, f^Y$ and independence?

Comment: It´s fine. You get the same result if you change the order of integration: $\int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} 2\cdot e^{-(x+2y)} \, dx \, dy=\frac23$ I don´t see a quicker way.

Comment: @callculus Thank you. Your answer is so short it has more character of a comment, but if that's all to consider I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer!

Comment: You´re welcome. I´ve posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculation is fine. You can double check your result by changing the order of integration.

$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} 2\cdot e^{-(x+2y)} \, dx \, dy=\frac23$$